# Añadir parámetros en un Intent ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: android, cámara

Estoy realizando una aplicación que añade botones dinámicamente que activen la cámara para realizar una foto.

```
botonCamara.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MISFOTOS");
        imagesFolder.mkdirs();
        String nombre = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss").format(new Date());
        File image = new File(imagesFolder, nombre +".jpg");
        Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);


        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
        cameraIntent.putExtra("IMG_ID", miImagen.getId());


        ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,1);
    }
});
```

Estos botones los creo programaticamente por lo que necesito identificarlos. Por este motivo intento enviar el identificador de la imagen como extra de la actividad.

Sé que si se le envía EXTRA_OUTPUT, en el activityResult, el Intent vienen nulo. Pero necesitaría de alguna forma obtener el identificador de la imagen a la cual estoy referenciando.

Este es el código del resultado del Activity, pero como digo, el parámetro data es nulo.

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        String idMiImagen = (String) extras.get("IMG_ID");

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            viewPager.findViewWithTag("imagen_"+idMiImagen).setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);

        }
    }
```

¿Hay alguna forma de enviarle un parámetro al Intent, y recuperarlo después en el Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno te explico un poco lo que estas entendiendo mal cuando envias esto en el intent de la camara `cameraIntent.putExtra("IMG_ID", miImagen.getId());` siginifica que estas enviando innformacion a la actividad de la camara nativa de android una vez dicho esto lo que recibes en el callback `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`.

Este intent data es la respuesta de tu actividad de la camara nativa osea internamente se envia un setResult con la respuesta que esa actividad de camara nativa envia osea eso no lo modificas tu. te lo digo para que entiendad por que lo envia no es lo q recibes es por que el resultado de esa actividad esta definido en la actividad nativa de la camara.

Ahora mis propuesta para lo q necesitas es sencilla tu solo puedes hacer un llamado a camara o recibir una respuesta a la vez, teniendo esto en cuenta create un atributo estatico `public static String id_img_pross = "";`

Ahora este atributo lo seteas asi:

```
botonCamara.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MISFOTOS");
        imagesFolder.mkdirs();
        String nombre = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss").format(new Date());
        File image = new File(imagesFolder, nombre +".jpg");
        Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);

        /** Guardas el id que estas procesando temporalmente **/
        id_img_pross = miImagen.getId();

        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);

        ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,1);
    }
});
```

y en el `onActivityResult` :

```
   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            viewPager.findViewWithTag("imagen_"+id_img_pross).setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);
            id_img_pross = ""; // reset del valor para evitar problemas

        }
    }
```

por cierto algo mas que no vi en tu código por lo general en la respuesta uno quiere la imagen que capturo si necesitas ayuda con eso me avisas.